# Unable to extract bulk ContentVersion and ContentDocumentLink data using Salesforce API

Tags: files, content, contentversion, contentdocumentlink

**Use Case:**
Transfer existing (and OOTB) Files that are linked with couple of custom objects (CO 1 & 2) to another Custom object (CO X)? The new custom object (CO X) has look up fields for CO 1 & CO 2 and and is associated with oob Files object as related item. *This is Not a migration of attachment to Files.

This is an interim solution that we intend to provide and hence, we are trying to avoid custom code.

**Steps done so far:**
1. Extracted bulk csv for **ContentDocument** object using workbench. As expected, Parent Id is blank. We have 4100 files in total- which are associated to many COs incl. CO 1, 2 & X.

2. Encountered the following error while trying to extract **ContentVersion object with VersionData** using DL, that is, even after reducing the batch size to 1.
   Error Message: 'Java heap error'.

I was able to query the above with WB, but only with one record shown at one time. However, received the following error while extracting bulk csv: 'Batch failed: Feature mot enabled: Binary field not supported when exporting related object'.

Only success was in extracting XML ContentVersion with VersionData using WB. This generated four separate xml files sized several hundreds of MBs each.

Can this be done differently and/or more efficiently?

3. Unable to extract **ContentDcoumentLink** data using either DL or WB due to the following: '**Implementation Restriction**: Content Documentlink requires a filter by a single id on Content DocumentId or LinkedEntity Id using the equals operator or multiple Ids included in the IN parameter'.

This is a huge roadblock considering that we have over 4000 Files in our org and checking the Linkedentity Id for each File is cumbersome to say the least.

Has anyone experienced a similar situation and gotten a solution to it? Please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could understand, You want to transfer the file linked to Custome object 1 and 2 to Custom Object 3. 
If you are not going for Custom code, On what basis you will transfer the file using DataLoader, WorkBench or DataLoader.io.

The problem is after getting the ContentDocumentLink in a spreadsheet, You need to manually change the LinkedEntityID for each file. For your Information, You can get the ContentDocumentLink through workbench as follows:-

```
select id, ContentDocumentId, LinkedentityId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedentityId in (select id from Custom_Object__c)
```

Also, ContentDocument having the field parentId is something different you are referring. Here ParentID is:-

> ID of the library that owns the document. Created automatically when
>   inserting a ContentVersion via the API for the first time.

As I would suggest you go with a Batch apex to transfer the file to the custom object record whatever you want. You will have more flexibility to control which file to be linked with which record.

- In your start method of the batch apex, you can query on Custom
  Object X.
- In your execute method, For each scope, you need to fetch the ids of
  Custom object 1 and Custom object 2 in a set.
- Then query the ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId equals to set of id containing the id of CO 1 and 2 for that scope.
- Then you need to Create a ContentDocumentLink with the LinkedEntityID according to your desired logic and delete the ContentDocumentLink for Existing one.

Comment: This is how I re-Linked Files to Co X.I. Execute the following query to fetch the following data. 
QUERY: SELECT ContentDocumentId,Id,LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId IN (select Id from CO1__c).

Comment: II. Execute the following query to fetch the following data.
QUERY: SELECT Id,Title FROM ContentDocument.

III. Use VLOOKUP to get following table. 

ContentDocumentId Id     LinkedEntityId  Title
0690G000005AUTvQAO 06A0G000005rB5mUAE a1z0G000029tlEVQAY Reporting Snapshots

Answer (score 0):

This is how I re-Linked Files to Co X.

I. Execute the following query to fetch the following data. 
QUERY: SELECT ContentDocumentId,Id,LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId IN (select Id from CO1__c).

II. Execute the following query to fetch the following data.
QUERY: SELECT Id,Title FROM ContentDocument.

III. Use VLOOKUP to get following table.

ContentDocumentId   Id                  LinkedEntityId      Title
0690G000005AUTvQAO  06A0G000005rB5mUAE  a1z0G000029tlEVQAY  Reporting Snapshots

IV. Next, insert new CO X records with the values in column D of the above table (Title: put this data in  Vyaire Note & Attachment Name), along with PI ID. Consider column C & D for VY N & A insert.

Once inserted, use the following query to fetch details of CO X that has been just created. 
Query: SELECT Id,Name FROM Vyaire_Note_Attachment__c.

Id                  Name
a200G000000TIPjQAO  Reporting Snapshots

V. Now create new Content Document Link records using the following table.

To prepare the insert table, use VLOOKUP with table in step # II (Use table in step # IV as the base table) to get the below table.
remember to ad another column for Share Type and put value = 'V'.

LinkedEntity Id     Content Document Id     Share Type
a200G000000TIPjQAO  0690G000005AUTvQAO      V

06A0G000005rCwnUAE  Success Created

Vi. Next, delete all CDL records in Step I. Use the Column named ID.

Now you are all set.